# How can I download an YouTube video thumbnail in Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I download YouTube video Thumbnail to my machine by creating a blob file from the YouTube API

Comment: You can use online tool to get YouTube thumbnail
https://www.workversatile.com/youtube-thumbnail-downloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to fetch it:

```
const youtube = (function () {
    let video, results;

    const getThumbnail = function (url, size) {
        if (url == null) {
            return '';
        }
    
        size = (size == null) ? 'big' : size;
        results = url.match('[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)');
        video = (results == null) ? url : results[1];

        if (size == 'small') {
            return `http://img.youtube.com/vi/${video}/2.jpg`;
        }

        return `http://img.youtube.com/vi/${video}/0.jpg`;
    };

    return {
        thumbnail: getThumbnail
    };
}());




//Example of usage:

const thumbnail = youtube.thumbnail("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tn6-PIqc4UM", "small")    

console.log(thumbnail);
```

Comment: Hey Alen can u please let me know what wrong in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265422/youtube-thumbnail-download-cors-error-on-firefox-and-safari-works-fine-on-chrom

Comment: @virendraparade Page not found. I cannot open it.

Comment: can you try out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269963/works-fine-in-chrome-but-access-control-allow-origin-missing-issues-in-firefox

Comment: @virendraparade I think the problem is because you're trying to fetch this from localhost, if you try to do that from production, it will work. Can you try to solve your problem with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) extension